# How to stop VBA macro when it reaches last row of Excel

Tags: excel, vba

How to stop VBA macro when it reaches last row of Excel.
Below is the code I've written. It executes well but gives error# 1004 upon reaching last row of excel spreadsheet.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
Range("a1048570").Select
Do
ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried with below but it doesnt even move down below the range A1048570 now.

`Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
Range("a1048570").Select
Do While ActiveCell < Range("a1048576")
ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
Loop
End Sub`

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO. Your workaround won't work because `Do While ActiveCell < Range("a1048576")` evaluates cell's values, i.e. it is the same as `ActiveCell.Value < Range("a1048576").Value`. If both cells are empty then this condition automatically fails.

In order to make it work you'd need to check row's number, something like:

```
Do While ActiveCell.Row < 1048576
```

Comment: Great! Its working. Can we also write as,
Do While ActiveCell.Row < lastrow

Comment: Absolutely! As long as `lastrow` is a valid number (i.e. datatype = `Long`)